# Python tagging and lemmatizing

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, pos-tagger, lemmatization

I've been reading through methods of tagging and lemmatizing for the past few days - and one issue I'm coming across is the POS tagging to lemmatization phase.

I've successfully managed to POS tag text using the [Perceptron tagger](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tag/perceptron.html), however when I move to lemmatize the text, due to the clear issues with POS labels, the [Wordnet lemmatizer](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.stem.html) fails.

I have read through SO workarounds involving relabeling tags using WordNet labels (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364493/lemmatizing-pos-tagged-words-with-nltk) and [also here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15586721/wordnet-lemmatization-and-pos-tagging-in-python)) - however I wonder about the efficiency of such a process. For tagging and then lemmatizing entire documents, or even larger texts, does the relabeling not pose an issue for slowing the whole event?

Is there no WordNet tagger that matches its own lemmatizer? Alternatively, are there other lemmatizers that match their tagger?

Any advice appreciated.

*edit: Perceptron tagger [pulls from treebank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38578100/what-is-the-tagset-for-nltk-perceptron-tagger), removed the example.

Comment: What do you mean by _due to the clear issues with POS labels, the Wordnet lemmatizer fails._ ?

Comment: When POS tagging with Perceptron, the WordNet lemmatizer doesn't recognize the Perceptron labels.

Comment: NLTK serves primarily educational purposes. If you care about speed and/or memory, at good accuracy, go for an industrial-strength solution like SpaCy.

Comment: Another alternative being gensim?